# No buffers in memory. What it means?

Tags: linux, debian, memory, memory-usage, openvz

This is a memory stats from my VPS (**OpenVZ**).

```
$ free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       800        405        394          0          0        405
-/+ buffers/cache:      0        800
Swap:        0          0          0
```

It hosts PHP stack (nginx, Apache, mod_php) + some Python apps via uWSGI, so **machine is not idle** anyway. Can anyone explain, why only cached memory is shown and buffers are always 0 (possibly, virtualization issue)? And what does `buffers` and `cached` memory values exactly mean?

PS: I've seen similar questions like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/458809/linux-buffer-memory-always-stays-at-zero), but they don't make it more clear...

Answer (score 2):

OpenVZ does not let you see how physical memory not assigned to you is being used. It shows only the memory assigned to you and how much of it is assigned to processes you created.

You will frequently find that for this reason and many similar other reasons, it is recommend that important applications be kept a safe, and large, distance away from OpenVZ.

Comment: «it is recommend that important applications be kept a safe, and large, distance away from OpenVZ». Just golden.

Comment: Not to mention that those stats given in the question are obviously broken. Zero memory used?!